# Page count after using PdfFileMerger() in pypdf2

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to use PdfFileMerger() in PyPDF2 to merge pdf files (see code).

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

[...]

merger = PdfFileMerger()

if (some condition):
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(file(filename1, 'rb')))
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(file(filename2, 'rb')))
if (test for non-zero file size):
    merger.write("output.pdf")
```

However, my merge commands are subject to certain conditions and it could turn out that no merged pdf file is generated. I would like to know how to determine the page count after performing merges using PdfFileMerger(). If nothing else, I would like to know if the number of pages is non-zero. Maintaining a counter to do this would be cumbersome because I am performing the merges across several functions and would prefer a more elegant solution.

Comment: Maybe create a wrapper around your merger object, which maintains page count and pass that around.

Comment: Yes, that is an option. Unlike PdfFileWriter, PdfFileMerger does not seem to have a method like getNumPages() and it seems like we have to create a wrapper object to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm +- in the same case as you. I will explain my solution. I'm not opening the PDFs with `PdfFileReader('filename.pdf', 'rb')` but I'm passing the pdfs content in an array for the merge (`pdfs_content_array`). Then I'm preparing the merger and my output (don't want to save the generated file locally so I have to use BytesIO to save the merged content somewhere) `calc_page_sum` is needed to compare the page number results. The most important part is: `calc_page_sum += PdfFileReader(bytes_content).getNumPages()` so I open the bytes content with PdfFileReader and get the pages number. Then I'm appending the merger `... merger.append,bytes_content` I'm writing the merge into my bytes output and compare it with the calc_page_sum. That's it.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
import io

[...]

def merge_the_pdfs(self,pdfs_content_array,output_file):
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    output = io.BytesIO()
    calc_page_sum = 0

    for content in pdfs_content_array:
        bytes_content = io.BytesIO(content)
        calc_page_sum += PdfFileReader(bytes_content).getNumPages()
        yield self.application.cpupool.submit(merger.append,bytes_content)

    merger.write(output)
    if not calc_page_sum == PdfFileReader(output).getNumPages():
        return None

    return output.getValue()
```

Hope this will help!

2nd Version:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
import io
import sys

filename1 = 'test.pdf'
filename2 = 'test1.pdf'

merger = PdfFileMerger()
output = io.BytesIO()
calc_page_sum = 0

filesarray = [filename1,filename2]

for singlefile in filesarray:
    calc_page_sum += PdfFileReader(singlefile, 'rb').getNumPages()
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(singlefile, 'rb'))

merger.write(output)
print(calc_page_sum)
print(PdfFileReader(output).getNumPages())

if calc_page_sum == PdfFileReader(output).getNumPages():
    print("It worked")
    merger.write("merging-test.pdf")
    sys.exit()

print("Didn't worked")
sys.exit()
```

Comment: As noted in my question, I agree that maintaining a counter (like calc_page_sum) can solve the problem. However, I was wondering if there is a better solution. For example, prior to using PdfFileMerger, I used PdfFileWriter, which has a getNumPages() method that solves the problem. However, PdfFileWriter was causing problems when too many files were opened and when I moved to PdfFileMerger, an equivalent method like getNumPages() is not available.

Comment: I didn't found another option. Instead of writting into a file `merger.write("output.pdf")` you can write the result into a BytesIO object then use PdfFileWriter to use getNumPages() and compare. If this will be true you can write the output again but then into the file.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you can try to use the following

```
if len(merger.pages) > 0
```

for your condition

```
if (test for non-zero file size)
```

Comment: `len(merger.pages)` does the trick.  This should be the accepted answer.